# Windows 7: Why does it run CHKDSK most restarts?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

It seems every time I restart my PC (W7 ultimate 64-bit) it runs CHKDSK. Is this normal, and if so is it configurable?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't normal. It typically happens either when it hasn't been run in a large amount of time (Not sure what this actually is) or when a hard drive related problem is detected.

It will try to run every time you start your machine until it is able to complete fully.

If you want to stop it, you can type:

```
chkntfs /x c:
```

(Replace `c:` with whatever drive is being checked).

It is also possible to remove `AutoCheck` from startup using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) or from Regedit directly, but I would not recommend this method.

Comment: aaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Something tells me @Wil typed faster than @John T here :P

Comment: @Ivo Flipse♦ Really? Post time shows that Wil answered at 09:39:28 and John T answered at 09:39:06 which is whole 22 seconds faster.

Comment: I just assumed that from @John T's response @AndrejaKo

Comment: @AndrejaKo - John T wrote the first paragraph of his answer, I then wrote my answer except for the last paragraph, he edited his to include chkntfs and then saw I already had it and made that comment, then I edited mine to add the last paragraph... Sometimes it would be easier to understand this site if there wasn't free edits!

Comment: Give this man his check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

It is normal if your machine isn't halting properly, or if you haven't let it run through fully yet. If you don't let chkdsk run, it will keep bugging you until you run it or disable it for that drive. Certain disk preservation software will enable disk checking on a schedule as well.

If you're sure the drive is fine, you can disable it in command line:

```
chkntfs /x c:
```

I'd strongly recommend letting it do it's thing though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reson why this should happen but have you tried Task Scheaukder to see if anything in that is causing it to happen.

Comment: This would be more suited to being a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by a failing hard drive.  This happened to me recently, in fact, when the RAID controller on my motherboard began to fail and files on my hard drive were becoming corrupted.  I didn't realize, until too late, what was happening and lost most of my recent data.

If this runs, let it run on a couple of boots and watch for any errors it may find.  If it does not find any errors after you watched it run a couple times, you're most likely ok and you can follow suggestions offered by others to alter the behavior.  If it's finding errors every time it runs, it could be pointing to a serious problem.  You are backing up your data frequently, right???  :)

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not normal. Maybe some of the suggestions [here](http://www.w7forums.com/chkdsk-always-runs-t1791.html) could help.

Comment: Perhaps listing what those suggestions are would be helpful